# metodo salvar: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

Tags: jsf, hibernate

Pessoal tenho uma pequena tela que cadastra nome e tipo. Quando clico em tipo Física é renderizado a data de nascimento e preciso salvar o mesmo e quando clico em Jurídico tenho que salvar um ramo de atividade que esta carregando os ramos corretamente no xhtml.

O problema é que no Físico gera o erro: Column 'codigo_ramo_atividade' cannot be null e no Jurídico gera o erro: Column 'data_nascimento' cannot be null.

OBS: Quando não renderizo os xhtml ele salva no banco de dados corretamente.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Tipo:" for="tipo" />
            <h:selectOneRadio id="tipo" value="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.tipo}" 
                required="true" label="Tipo pessoa" immediate="true"
                valueChangeListener="#{cadastroPessoaBean.tipoPessoaAlterado}"
                onchange="submit();">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoas}" var="pessoa"
                    itemLabel="#{pessoa.descricao}" itemValue="#{pessoa}" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>

<h:outputLabel value="Data de nascimento:" rendered="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.tipo eq 'FISICA'}" />
            <h:inputText size="12" value="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.dataNascimento}"
                required="true" label="Data de nascimento" rendered="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.tipo eq 'FISICA'}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputLabel value="Ramo de atividade:" rendered="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.tipo eq 'JURIDICA'}"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.ramoAtividade}" required="true"
                label="Ramo de atividade" rendered="#{cadastroPessoaBean.pessoa.tipo eq 'JURIDICA'}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel=":: Selecione ::" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroPessoaBean.ramosAtividades}" var="ramoAtividade"
                    itemLabel="#{ramoAtividade.descricao}" itemValue="#{ramoAtividade}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Bean:

```
public void cadastrar() {
    Session session = (Session) FacesUtil.getRequestAttribute("session");

    session.merge(this.pessoa);

    this.pessoa = new Pessoa();

public void tipoPessoaAlterado(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    this.pessoa.setTipo((TipoPessoa) event.getNewValue());
    this.pessoa.setDataNascimento(null);
    this.pessoa.setRamoAtividade(null); //new RamoAtividade()

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o meu erro primário, o problema é que no banco de dados o campo data_nascimento e ramo_atividade estavam com not null e na minha implementação estava usando a Restrictions eq.

Solução: No banco de dados, na tabela pessoa foi necessário definir esses dois campos como não requeridos (NOT NULL = FALSE) e na implementação em vez de eq alterei para Restrictions.eqOrIsNull.